# Get List of subcategory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this category on my wordpress:

```
Test1
  - Sub1OfTest1
  - Sub2OfTest1
Test2
  - Sub1OfTest2
  - Sub2OfTest2
```

Now iam at url: `http://localhost/wordpress/category/test1`
I write the following code on file `category-test1.php`

```
<?php
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=2');

print_r($categories);
foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>

        <div class="qitem">
            <a href="<?php get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->name; ?>">
                <?php echo $category->name; ?>
            </a>
            <h4>
                <span class="caption">
                    <?php echo $category->name; ?>
                </span>
            </h4>
            <p>
                <span class="caption">
                    <?php echo $category->description; ?>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

I'm trying to show sub category of Test1 but the code only return array(). What did I miss?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is that category empty? By default WordPress hides emptr categories. try:

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=2&hide_empty=0');
```

**Edit:** Fixed, thank you  @Stoep

Comment: yes, there are no post have category Test1. I try adding hide_empty=false but it didn't work. I try the code on wordpress default theme, and also didn't work

But after I try using array parameter (not using string) it works. 

$categories = get_categories(array(
 'child_of' => 4,
 'hide_empty' => false
));

print_r($categories);

Thanks for reminding me using hide_empty parameter

Comment: hide_empty=false does not work because false is seen as a string. You should instead use: hide_empty=0

Answer (score 0):

The `child_of` argument of `get_categories` specifies the category by it's ID - assuming you created your categories in order, the code `get_categories('child_of=2')` is probably requesting the subcategories of Sub1OfTest1.

To get the ID of a category, go to Posts → Categories and click on a category. The cat_ID will be in the url of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The ID of category Test1 is 2, I have checked it by hovering the link to edit category.

Answer (score 0):

try this too - [Show wordpress subcategories only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163261/show-wordpress-subcategories-only/)

that topic might help too, as there are different solutions for showing subcategories.

Answer (score 0):

//This is coding of getting sub category and sub-sub category

```
    $args = array
    (
        'number'     => $number,
        'orderby'    => 'title',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'include'    => array(11,281,28,51,99,93,33,55,107,20),
        'exclude'    => array(32,29),
    );
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($product_categories);
    // echo '</pre>';

    foreach($product_categories as $data):
        if($data->slug = 'cooking')
        {
            $child_arg = array('hide_empty'=>false,'parent'=>$data->term_id,'exclude'=>array(32,29));
        }
        else
        {
            $child_arg = array('hide_empty'=>false,'parent'=>$data->term_id);
        }
        $child_terms = get_terms('product_cat',$child_arg);
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($child_terms);
        // echo "</pre>";
        foreach($child_terms as $data1):
            if($data1->slug = 'cooking')
            {
                $sub_child_arg = array('hide_empty'=>false,'parent'=>$data1->term_id,'exclude'=>array(32,29));
            }
            else
            {
                $sub_child_arg = array('hide_empty'=>false,'parent'=>$data1->term_id);
            }
            $sub_child_terms = get_terms('product_cat',$sub_child_arg);
            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($sub_child_terms);
            // echo "</pre>";
        endforeach;
    endforeach; 
?>
```