# Show wordpress subcategories only

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have 7 Categories (parents), and every category has 15 sub-categories.

When I select some category (parent), I want to display only sub-categories (children) of that particular parent category (parent).

After I click on sub-category (child) then it should display its posts only.

I have a `fron_page.php` and `category.php`.

How can I write this to first show sub-categories separately, then post of that sub-category separately in new file, which user want to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should help you:

```
<ul> 
<?php 
 $cats = get_the_category();
 $mycat = $cats->cat_ID;
    wp_list_categories('orderby=id&child_of='.$mycat); 
?>
</ul>
```

OR

```
<?php
if (is_category()) {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('hide_empty=0&hierarchical=true&orderby=id&show_count=0&title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID."&echo=0");
    if($this_category !='<li>No categories</li>')
    {
     echo '<ul>'.$this_category.'</ul>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Let me know please.

Good luck! :)

Comment: i can succefully show sub categories of a catgeory  problem is this i want show sub category posts in a seprate page in this senerio posts of sub category display on same pag(category page). how to make seprate file to show only posts nothing more to display in that seprate file

Comment: thnx your code is working like a charm.... can is possible to hide on category page perent categorty postt.. same in code it display sub category but below it display all the post of that  parent category

Comment: Yes, sure, it is possible, but please respect this site's rules and open another question on this site with the new question :)

Comment: Is there any way to show categories instead of list items or `wp_list_categories()`?

Comment: Yes, of course. Please feel free to open a topic with your question.

Answer (score 0):

1) Showing only Subcategories:

```
<?php
    // if the page visitor views is a category page
if (is_category())
{
$cur_cat = get_query_var('cat');
    if ($cur_cat) 
    {
        $new_cats = wp_list_categories('echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_cat . '&depth=1&title_li=&&show_count=1&hide_empty=0');
        echo '<ul>' . $new_cats . '</ul>';
    }
}
?>
```

2) Showing All Top Categories:

```
<?php 
wp_list_categories('depth=1&title_li=&exclude=1&show_count=1&hide_empty=0');
?>
```

3) Showing All Top Categories + Subcategories like a Tree menu:

```
Use plugin, called FoCal
```

4) view this topic

```
http://wpworks.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/displaying-categories-and-subcategories-tree-on-wordpress/
```