# Wordpress: showing posts of subcategories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I searched a lot for this but couldn't find a working solution for my exact problem.

What I am looking for is:

> **On category parent page:**
>
> Child category title I
>
> > Display X posts of subcategory
>
> Child category title II
>
> > Display X posts of subcategory
>
> Posts with no subcategory selected, but do have the parent
>
> > Display all other posts of parent category
>
> etc..

And then for

> **On category child page:**
>
> Display all posts

I am looking for a solution I can write within the loop like this:

```php
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

etc. (I hope everyone understands what I mean).

I am really thankful if some one helps me out, it's even better if it's with a little bit explanation of the result!

Comment: You can see the issue that same this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163261/show-wordpress-subcategories-only

Comment: Yes, but then it's not showing any posts. And also, on a child category page it says 'no categories'. I wish I had the skills to edit that piece of code to my own wishes, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly see the screenshot: [image: See and create subcatagory]

Then,

Follow the code here: [Show wordpress subcategories only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163261/show-wordpress-subcategories-only)

Comment: Thanks, I already have it like the screen, but again, this does not resolve my issue. On parent category pages, it outputs a list of all existing subcategory's. Then I also need the POSTS of the listed subpages below it. And on the subcategory page, that script gives me 'no categories', while I need ALL POSTS of that certain subcategory listed there. Could you help me with this?

Comment: I edited the original post a slight bit, it might make it more clear.