# How to display child-category of a parent category

Tags: wordpress

How to get subcategories of current category in a page? Our code is here

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$category = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'category', true );

print_r( $category);
```

Comment: Could give up a bit more context, I assume you want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163261/show-wordpress-subcategories-only

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a category from current query and put one clause 'child_of' in argument.Please check following code :

```
$current_cat = get_queried_object();

$args = array( 'child_of' => $current_cat->term_id, );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
//print_r($categories );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Comment: it display all category nd subcategory

Comment: You need to modify code according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This code has worked for me.

```
<?php
    if (is_category()) {
    $this_category = get_category($cat);
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    if($this_category->category_parent)
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=0
    &title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->category_parent.
    "&echo=0"); else
    $this_category = wp_list_categories('orderby=id&depth=1&show_count=0
    &title_li=&use_desc_for_title=1&child_of='.$this_category->cat_ID.
    "&echo=0");
    if ($this_category) { ?> 

<ul>
<?php echo $this_category; ?>

</ul>

<?php } ?>
```